# How to move the relative clause in this sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clauses

I wrote:

> As can be observed from Figure 3, there exist sufficient white pixels on the edges of the pallet car, that reside on a straight line.

Should I use "that reside on a straight line" close to "sufficient white pixels"? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: Without knowing what Figure 3 looks like, it's a challenge to understand what the sentence is meant to express.

Comment: If they're on the edge, they must be on a straight line.  Is it a sufficient number of white pixels that is needed?

Comment: @TRomano the edge may not be completely strait and slightly bent, but majority of pixels reside on a straight line.

Comment: That goes to show that it is difficult to give you sound advice when you supply very limited context.  I don't understand the plural, **edges**, then. Are there several straight lines?

Comment: Get rid of the existential construction "there exist" and the ponderous "as can be observed from...". Something like:  *In Figure 3, the number of white pixels that reside on (a) straight line(s) along the pallet car's edge(s)  is sufficient to determine....*  Again, not sure about the plurals.

Comment: @TRomano thank you! For example suppose a rectangular shape. I suppose four edges for such a shape. The pixels residing on each of which can form an straight line.

Comment: In not very plain English, *As can be observed in Figure 3, there exist sufficient collinear white pixels on the edges of the pallet car.* In plain English, *Figure 3 shows (that there are) some white pixels on the edges of the pallet car. The amount of these white pixels is sufficient.*

Comment: Since there are four edges:  *In Figure 3, the number of white pixels that reside on a straight line along each edge of the top of the pallet car is sufficient to determine...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily, but the best choice depends on which details you would like to emphasize. I don't know the context of the sentence, so a few options are below to hopefully cover this specific use case (there could well be a couple suitable stylistic approaches):

**a.) "...there exist sufficient white pixels on the edges of the pallet car that reside on a straight line."**

--> This implies that it's important that *these* pixels reside on a straight line vs. others on the edges of the pallet.  Stylistically it's a bit wordy.

**b.) "...there exist sufficient white pixels on the edges of the pallet car, which reside on a straight line."**

--> This implies that there exist sufficient pixels on the edges of the pallet car, and they happen to also be in a straight line (for the reader's reference).

**c.) "...there exist sufficient white pixels residing/that reside on a straight line on the edges of the pallet car."**

--> Similar to a.) and probably stylistically cleaner; implies that it's important that these pixels reside on a straight line as a defining characteristic of these pixels

**d.) "...there exist sufficient white pixels, residing on a straight line on the edges of the pallet car."**

--> Similar to f.) implies that there are sufficient white pixels in general, and that you can see them residing on a straight line on the edges of the pallet car.

**d.) "...there exist sufficient white pixels, which reside on a straight line, on the edges of the pallet car."**

--> Similar to b.); emphasizes that there are sufficient white pixels on the edges of the pallet car, and that they area also in a straight line (for reference).

**f.) "...there exist sufficient white pixels, which reside on a straight line on the edges of the pallet car."**

--> Implies in that there are sufficient white pixels (in general)and that they happen to both reside on a straight line and be on the edges of the pallet car.

Comment: There is entirely too much existing and residing going on here, @Ahmad . It's overly complicated, hard to fathom, and unnecessarily verbose. Try this: _"...there are sufficient white pixels on a straight line on the edges of the pallet car."_